# How to Make Menu Active

Tags: php, jquery, html, css

I have menu as follows

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
</ul>
```

how to make it Active when I visit that Page. I tried as follows but no luck

```
#navigation a:active {
    color: #000;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#DFE7FA), to(#FFF));
    border-bottom-width:0px;
}
```

I'm new webie thanks for any suggestions

Comment: do you want it to change the color when you have visited it or when you click on it?

Comment: How do you know what page you are on? Do you use php (or javascript / jQuery...) to detect that?

Comment: @jeroen Can't the page have its own contents? Do you *really* need JavaScript to detect the contents of the page?

Comment: @PraveenKumar To style a specific menu item for the active page, you first need to determine what page is active. You can do that using php or css (common) but if really needed, you could do that using javascript as well by reading the url in the address bar. Just adding random classes to html elements completely bypasses that step and is not very useful IMO.

Comment: @PraveenKumar And you should not remove the php tag. If the OP is using that, it would be the best tool to generate for example the code in your own answer.

Comment: Okay I agree with you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add id to your code as below

**Update**

```
<div id="menu">
  <ul>
    <li id="myHome"><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Write Script as Below

```
<script>
  window.onload = menuSelect('myHome');
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Each page has a class on the body tag that identifies it:

**BODY OF HOME PAGE:**

```
<body class="home">
<ul>
    <li><a href="index.php" class="home">Home</a></li> //Each navigation item also includes a class identifying that particular link.
    <li><a href="aboutUs.php" class="aboutUs">About Us</a></li>
</ul>
</body>
```

**BODY OF ABOUT US PAGE:**

```
<body class="aboutUs">
<ul>
    <li><a href="index.php" class="home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="aboutUs.php" class="aboutUs">About Us</a></li>
</ul>
</body>
```

Then you target those classes in your CSS, defining a different state for the current page:

**CSS STYLE:**

```
body.home a.home, body.aboutUs a.aboutUs{
//HERE GOES YOUR CSS
color: #000;
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#DFE7FA), to(#FFF));
border-bottom-width:0px;

}
```

Comment: Won't this go off when user refreshes the page?

Comment: I don't think this would be even a JavaScript or jQuery question! Please read it fully!

Comment: Yes praveen, you were right. I hope the answer above does the right job

Comment: Nice, this is the only answer that actually addresses the problem of determining what page you are on.

Answer (score 0):

In your `index.php` page, you need to edit the HTML this way:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="index.php" class="active">Home</a></li>
</ul>
```

In other pages, say `about.php`, you might have something like this:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="about.php" class="active">About</a></li>
</ul>
```

And change the CSS to `.active` and not `:active`, as the second one is a state of element:

```css
#navigation a.active {
    color: #000;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#DFE7FA), to(#FFF));
    border-bottom-width:0px;
}
```

Comment: He then still needs some code to determine which menu element is the current active page.

Comment: @Gerton Man, just aded it!

Comment: this highly depends on if he's using a framework and if so which. If you're using templates just adding the class active to a random menu item isn't going to cut it.

Comment: Yes. But since that he didn't say any more details, it is assumed that he is not using anything, and also I assume that he's a newbie trying out stuff and this one is a basic explanation!

Answer (score 0):

The `:active` pseudo-selector is for when an element is well, active, for example while a link is *being clicked*.

What you will need to do is give your `<a>` element a class attribute and style it accordingly.